# Unit testing with AutoMapper using DeploymentItem attribute not working - PlatformNotSupportedException

Tags: c#, unit-testing, automapper-3

I'm trying to use AutoMapper with my unit tests that use DeploymentItem attributes in order to read files at runtime.

Here is my code:

```
    [TestClass]
    public class UnitTest1
    {
        [TestMethod]
        [DeploymentItem("Samples/demo.csv")]
        public void TestMethod1()
        {
            Mapper.CreateMap<A, B>();

            // test logic
        }
    }

    class A
    {
        public string PropA { get; set; }
        public bool PropB { get; set; }
    }

    class B
    {
        public string PropA { get; set; }
        public bool PropB { get; set; }
    }
```

I'm getting an error at this line:

```
Mapper.CreateMap<A, B>();
```

**but when I remove the DeploymentItem attribute the test just works fine.**

I have read [this article](http://lostechies.com/jimmybogard/2013/09/04/automapper-3-0-portable-class-libraries-and-platformnotsupportedexception/) from the creator of AutoMapper but doesn't seem to addressing the problem.

Exception details below:

```
System.TypeInitializationException was unhandled by user code
  HResult=-2146233036
  Message=The type initializer for 'AutoMapper.TypeMapFactory' threw an exception.
  Source=AutoMapper
  TypeName=AutoMapper.TypeMapFactory
  StackTrace:
       at AutoMapper.TypeMapFactory..ctor()
       at AutoMapper.Mapper.<.cctor>b__0()
       at AutoMapper.Internal.LazyFactory.LazyImpl`1.get_Value()
       at AutoMapper.Mapper.get_ConfigurationProvider()
       at AutoMapper.Mapper.get_Configuration()
       at AutoMapper.Mapper.CreateMap[TSource,TDestination]()
       at TNS.T4.MVC.Tests.Mocks.UnitTest1.TestMethod1() in c:\tns.visualstudio.com\Research Platform\Development\T4\TNS.T4.MVC.Tests\Mocks\UnitTest1.cs:line 13
  InnerException: System.PlatformNotSupportedException
       HResult=-2146233031
       Message=This type is not supported on this platform IDictionaryFactory
       Source=AutoMapper
       StackTrace:
            at AutoMapper.Internal.PlatformAdapter.Resolve[T](Boolean throwIfNotFound)
            at AutoMapper.TypeMapFactory..cctor()
       InnerException:
```

Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to SO, Javier.

Comment: Reg:- "but when I remove the DeploymentItem attribute the test just works fine." Are you sure about this. I get the same error even without the DeploymentItem attribute

Comment: Raj, thank you for your answer. Just replicated the error again on a new project and still gettim the same error. That's interesting, i'm using VS 2012 11.0.60315.01 Update 2 with .Net 4.5 and resharper 7.1.3 full and still getting the same situation as above

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think this is Deployment Item related. I replicated the issue, but went away after installing install-package AutoMapper.NET35

Comment: I had installed AutoMapper package and just installed the one you mentioned and did the trick. Thank you!